# Помогите решить ошибку java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate ordinal parameter [1], expecting one of []

Tags: spring, hibernate

Здраздвуйте Разрабы тут вопрос по Spring + Hibernate

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[dispatcher]: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate ordinal parameter [1], expecting one of []
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.ParameterMetadataImpl.getOrdinalParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadataImpl.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.ParameterMetadataImpl.getQueryParameter(ParameterMetadataImpl.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingsImpl.getBinding(QueryParameterBindingsImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:511)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:106)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:141)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:101)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bindAndPrepare(ParameterBinder.java:161)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bindAndPrepare(ParameterBinder.java:152)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.NamedQuery.doCreateQuery(NamedQuery.java:161)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.createQuery(AbstractJpaQuery.java:202)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:125)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:89)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:128)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:118)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:494)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:477)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy464.findByUserID(Unknown Source)
    at kz.starter.app.ekpd.service.FinalService.find_item_by_user(FinalService.java:36)
    at kz.starter.app.ekpd.service.FinalService.getRegistryNames(FinalService.java:48)
    at kz.starter.app.ekpd.service.FinalService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e23b0781.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at kz.starter.app.ekpd.service.FinalService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ea5bcacf.getRegistryNames(<generated>)
    at kz.starter.app.ekpd.controller.restController.getRegistryNameByUserId(restController.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

как можно решить данную ошибку?

RegistryRoutes Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "registry_routes")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "RegistryRoutes.findAll", query = "SELECT r FROM RegistryRoutes r")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "RegistryRoutes.findByRegistryID", query = "SELECT r FROM RegistryRoutes r WHERE r.registryRoutesPK.registryID = :registryID")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "RegistryRoutes.findByEventType", query = "SELECT r FROM RegistryRoutes r WHERE r.registryRoutesPK.eventType = :eventType")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "RegistryRoutes.findByRouteType", query = "SELECT r FROM RegistryRoutes r WHERE r.registryRoutesPK.routeType = :routeType")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "RegistryRoutes.findByRouteID", query = "SELECT r FROM RegistryRoutes r WHERE r.routeID = :routeID")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "RegistryRoutes.findByShowOnSave", query = "SELECT r FROM RegistryRoutes r WHERE r.showOnSave = :showOnSave")})
public class RegistryRoutes implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected RegistryRoutesPK registryRoutesPK;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 36)
    @Column(name = "routeID")
    private String routeID;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "showOnSave")
    private boolean showOnSave;
    @JoinColumn(name = "registryID", referencedColumnName = "registryID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Registries registries;

    public RegistryRoutes() {
    }

    public RegistryRoutes(RegistryRoutesPK registryRoutesPK) {
        this.registryRoutesPK = registryRoutesPK;
    }

    public RegistryRoutes(RegistryRoutesPK registryRoutesPK, String routeID, boolean showOnSave) {
        this.registryRoutesPK = registryRoutesPK;
        this.routeID = routeID;
        this.showOnSave = showOnSave;
    }

    public RegistryRoutes(String registryID, int eventType, int routeType) {
        this.registryRoutesPK = new RegistryRoutesPK(registryID, eventType, routeType);
    }

    public RegistryRoutesPK getRegistryRoutesPK() {
        return registryRoutesPK;
    }

    public void setRegistryRoutesPK(RegistryRoutesPK registryRoutesPK) {
        this.registryRoutesPK = registryRoutesPK;
    }

    public String getRouteID() {
        return routeID;
    }

    public void setRouteID(String routeID) {
        this.routeID = routeID;
    }

    public boolean getShowOnSave() {
        return showOnSave;
    }

    public void setShowOnSave(boolean showOnSave) {
        this.showOnSave = showOnSave;
    }

    public Registries getRegistries() {
        return registries;
    }

    public void setRegistries(Registries registries) {
        this.registries = registries;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (registryRoutesPK != null ? registryRoutesPK.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof RegistryRoutes)) {
            return false;
        }
        RegistryRoutes other = (RegistryRoutes) object;
        if ((this.registryRoutesPK == null && other.registryRoutesPK != null) || (this.registryRoutesPK != null && !this.registryRoutesPK.equals(other.registryRoutesPK))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "kz.starter.app.ekpd.dto.RegistryRoutes[ registryRoutesPK=" + registryRoutesPK + " ]";
    }

}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface RegistryRoutesRepository extends JpaRepository<RegistryRoutes, Serializable>{
    public RegistryRoutes findByRouteID(String routeID);
}
```

Comment: мне кажется или в query нужно писать `FROM RegistryRoutes r ` всесто `SELECT r FROM RegistryRoutes ` ?

Comment: но можно писать как `SELECT r FROM registry_routes `